# hadoop multiple nodes set up with ssh port different from 22

Tags: hadoop, installation

I am setting up Hadoop on two linux servers following this link:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/

For security reason, I used different ssh port from 22. I set up .ssh/config so that master and slave can ssh to each other. But I get the following Error on slave:

ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.net.UnknownHostException: unknown host: master

Any one know why I get this and how to fix it?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you put an entry in /etc/hosts file for master and slave ?

Comment: Since I can ssh between master and slave with set up in .ssh/config, I didn't put an entry in /etc/hosts. After I put an entry in /etc/hosts for both master and slave, I can run the hadoop successfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you also check if you are able to ssh master<->slave??